# Identify the class type in validation time that generates from same abstract class

Tags: java, validation, abstract-class

I have an abstract class named Company with some properties. Two different types of classes created by extending this abstract class. I have to add a custom validation in the abstract class. When the request came, I have to identify the type of the class. I have used 'instance of' for checking the type but it not working as expected. How do I check that ?

```
@UniqueCode(columnName = "companyCode")
public abstract class Company {
private String companyCode;
private String companyName;
// some other code
}

public class PsiCompany extends Company {
  private Long id;
}

public class IndentAgent extends Company {
  private Long id;
  private String cbRegNo;
}

public class UniqueCodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueCode, Object> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(UniqueCode constraintAnnotation) {}

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

     /*
     * How do I know the class type from object ?
     */
  }
}
```

Whenever I sent IndentAgent object it works fine but if I sent PsiCompany object it also goes in IndentAgent code blocks. How can I identify the class type from the object in isValid() method ?

Comment: try using `IndentAgent.class.isInstance(value)` as your if conditon

Comment: `if (value instanceof IndentAgent) { ... } else (value instanceof PsiCompany) { ... }` it's not valid Java

Comment: @ShreyGarg why would `IndentAgent.class.isInstance(value)` work any better than `value instanceof IndentAgent` here?

Comment: @Andrew, i know value instance of IndentAgent not working. What will be the best way to get the class type ?

Comment: `value instanceof IndentAgent` and `value instanceof PsiCompany` should work? Can you please show how you used those in your code which is failing?

Comment: I have solved in a different way. In each class, I have changed the property name class name + Id, instead of just Id.

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value instanceof PsiCompany) {
        System.out.println("PsiCompany");
        // do your thing
    } else if (value instanceof IndentAgent) {
        System.out.println("IndentAgent");
        // do your other thing
    }
    // return bool
}
```

Comment: It will not work. I did that at first. But when PsiCompany object sent, it cant be distinguished between PsiCompany and IndentAgent class casue both have id property.

Comment: Try again, it should work. I tried it just now just to double check https://imgur.com/a/009Js4Y